# Help with ASP.NET HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net

I began to learn ASP.NET and C#, to get more familiar with techniques I want to make plugin for open source [BugTracker.Net](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) application. Where I am stacked is that for adding new issue application need to get HttpWebRequest on insert_bug.aspx

I did make basic thing working on code like this:

```
string Url = "http://localhost:8090/insert_bug.aspx";
        string post_data =
                     "&username=admin"
                    + "&password=admin"
                    + "&short_desc=Description"
                    + "&comment=Comment"
                    + "&projectid=1"

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_data);
        HttpWebResponse res = null;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);
            req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            req.PreAuthenticate = 
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength=bytes.Length;
            Stream request_stream = req.GetRequestStream();
            request_stream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
            request_stream.Close();
            res = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HttpWebRequest error url=" + Url);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

I want to insert also CATEGORY into my issues and reading code on insert_bug.aspx i fund part for defining category for opening issue

```
if (Request["$CATEGORY$"] != null && Request["$CATEGORY$"] != "") { categoryid = Convert.ToInt32(Request["$CATEGORY$"]); }
```

Question:
What and How I can add "$CATEGORY$" to my request so the issues I added have defined category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, if you want to add a category, you need to look up the category ID and add it as a variable in your POST data. For example, if the category you want has its ID=1 ("bug" in BugTracker.NET), then you'd use this:

```
    string post_data =
                 "&username=admin"
                + "&password=admin"
                + "&short_desc=Description"
                + "&comment=Comment"
                + "&projectid=1"
                + "&$CATEGORY$=1";
```

BTW, in simple HTTP client scenarios like this one you're better off using the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) class.  You can accomplish the same thing in many fewer lines of code.