# Looking for a C# ticketing system (frontend helpdesk) that I could customize and integrate with Redmine

Tags: c#, tool-rec

Ideally the system should be open-source so that I could fine tune it with time and add very specific functions. It would be great if it was written in MVC but Asp.Net web forms would also be ok.
I need the system to look for incoming messages to a certain email account and add them to the system. I will also want to write a script to import all previously received emails into the system.
I am now looking into the system "sinergia": 
http://help-desk-framework.blogspot.com/

Did someone work with this? Is there something more active and with more functions?

I think this system doesn't create tickets automatically using emails from a certain account, but I might be wrong.

Edit: Looking more at the competition I found that OTRS has more functionalities out of the box. and I am thinking I could write my additional functionalities in C# in web services and call those functions from Perl. Do you think this is easy to do? will I encounter problems?
I didn't find a guide on how to do this, and in stackoverflow people didn't reply to this same question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538049/using-web-service-from-otrs

Maybe it's too difficult?

Answer (score 2):

I was researching this a while back when we were considering replacing our helpdesk software.  We ended up keeping our current product, as the cost of retraining and re-doing all the integration points for a new package was too high.  Assuming you don't have these issues, this is a good place to start: http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/

Comment: Funny enough, Redmine is on this list.

Comment: Thanks, but I had seen that list already. But looking at it again seem that Bugtracker.Net is more complete. If you have a better suggestion please let me know.

Comment: No, sorry.  As I said, we ended up sticking with our existing vendor's solution. (HEAT from FrontRange if it matters)  It's definitely not free (or even close) so it wouldn't help you.  I just remembered this list, and seeing some interesting prospects on it.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will still vote up your answer as looking at it again made me re-evaluate Bugtracker.net. I think I'll use that one unless something better comes up.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) it is open source and have e mail integration, also great thing that it have API for [adding new BUGs using http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936717/help-with-asp-net-httpwebrequest), so scripting old e mails should not be so hard

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used OTRS and I found it to be SO good that I didn't need much customization. The small changes to the code that I needed I directly did them in Perl even if I didn't know this language before, and considering the quality of the software it is well worth the effort. I definitely recommend it.